# Opengl managing buffer bindings with RAII

Tags: c++, opengl

I wanted to write a c++ wrapper class for buffer bindings. It was supposed to bind buffer to a target on creation, and on destruction restore previously bound buffer. The code I wrote looks like this:

```
class buffer {
private:
    GLuint name;
    GLenum target;
    GLenum targetBinding;

    GLenum getBindingEnumFromTarget (GLenum targ) {
        switch (targ) {
            case GL_ARRAY_BUFFER:
                return GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_BINDING;
            case GL_ATOMIC_COUNTER_BUFFER:
                return GL_ATOMIC_COUNTER_BUFFER_BINDING;
            case GL_COPY_READ_BUFFER:
                return GL_COPY_READ_BUFFER_BINDING;
            case GL_COPY_WRITE_BUFFER:
                return GL_COPY_WRITE_BUFFER_BINDING;
            case GL_DISPATCH_INDIRECT_BUFFER:
                return GL_DISPATCH_INDIRECT_BUFFER_BINDING;
            case GL_DRAW_INDIRECT_BUFFER:
                return GL_DRAW_INDIRECT_BUFFER_BINDING;
            case GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER:
                return GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER_BINDING;
            case GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER:
                return GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER_BINDING;
            case GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER:
                return GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER_BINDING;
            case GL_QUERY_BUFFER:
                return GL_QUERY_BUFFER_BINDING;
            case GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER:
                return GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER_BINDING;
            case GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER:
                return GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER_BINDING;
            case GL_TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK_BUFFER:
                return GL_TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK_BUFFER_BINDING;
            case GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER:
                return GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER_BINDING;
            default:
                return 0;
        }
    }
public:
    class binding {
        private:
            GLenum target;
            GLuint previousName;
        public:
            binding (GLenum _target, GLuint _previousName) :target (_target), previousName (_previousName) {}
            binding (const binding & r) = delete;
            binding & operator = (const binding & r) = delete;
            ~binding () {
                glBindBuffer (target, previousName);
            }
    };
    binding bind () {
        GLint previousName;
        glGetIntegerv (targetBinding, &previousName);
        glBindBuffer (target, name);
        return binding {target, static_cast<GLuint>(previousName)};
    }
    buffer (GLenum _target) : target (_target), targetBinding (getBindingEnumFromTarget (target)){
        glCreateBuffers (1, &name);
    }
    buffer (const buffer & r) = delete;
    buffer & operator = (const buffer & r) = delete;
    ~buffer () {
        glDeleteBuffers (1, &name);
    }
};
```

And it works (the wrapper is `buffer::binding`). The code behaves how I wanted. But now I have two questions based on what I read on the internet:

- Is there a way to get the (BUFFER_TYPE)_BINDING enum from BUFFER_TYPE without the giant switch I used? The switch seems hard to read and maintain, and in the future there can be new types of buffers which would have to be added
- Should the `glGetIntegerv` be done at all in this context? I've read that using it is very slow because it requires syncing opengl commands.

Comment: Buffer objects are not typed; there is no reason why you cannot bind a buffer for vertex data and transform feedback (and indeed, there are plenty of good reasons for doing so). A buffer object class *should not* have a "target" directly associated with it.

Comment: For this to be truly RAII, `glBindBuffer()` should be called in `binding`'s constructor, instead of in `bind()`.

Answer (score 0):

Uhm, firstly you are using `glCreateBuffers` *(which is a newer DSA method, and a good thing!)*, however then you go and mess up by using `glBindBuffers` :( *(which is legacy rubbish, and not a good thing!)*.

I'd ***strongly*** recommend using `glVertexArrayVertexBuffer(s)` and `glVertexArrayElementBuffer` instead of `glBindBuffer`! Once you do that, the entire need for `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` et al, is entirely removed from your code; therefore there is zero need to care about the current buffer bindings at all. Tada! :)

In general, for any other OpenGL resource types, stick to the following DSA API methods:

- **Buffers** - `glCreateBuffers` / `glNamedBufferStorage` / `glDeleteBuffers`
- **Textures** - `glCreateTexture` / `glTextureStorage2D` / `glTextureSubImage` / `glDeleteTexture`
- **Samplers** - `glCreateSamplers` / `glSamplerParameter` / `glDeleteSamplers`
- **VAO** - `glCreateVertexArrays` / `glEnableVertexArrayAttrib` / `glVertexArrayAttribBinding /` glVertexArrayVertexBuffer`/`glDeleteVertexArrays`
- **VAO buffer bindings** - `glVertexArrayVertexBuffer(s)` / `glVertexArrayElementBuffer`

Mixing `glCreateFoo` and `glBindFoo` functions is basically a bit of an error I'm afraid....

The way RAII works is to allocate in the constructor, and then deallocate everything in the destructor. If you can also adhere to the `Single Responsibility Principle` *(i.e. Buffer + Binding is two responsibilities!)*, then this will dramatically simplify your code overall. Calling *glBindAnything* modifies global state, which somewhat breaks the principle of RAII....

I've ripped the following out of some of my old GL code. Hopefully it'll give you a few ideas.

```cpp
class Buffer {
public:

    enum StorageBit {
        kDynamic = GL_DYNAMIC_STORAGE_BIT,
        kMapRead = GL_MAP_READ_BIT,
        kMapWrite = GL_MAP_WRITE_BIT,
        kMapPersistent = GL_MAP_PERSISTENT_BIT,
        kMapCoherent = GL_MAP_COHERENT_BIT, 
        kClient = GL_CLIENT_STORAGE_BIT
    };
    typedef GLbitfield StorageBits;

    enum MapFlag {
        kReadOnly = GL_READ_ONLY,
        kWriteOnly = GL_WRITE_ONLY, 
        kReadWrite = GL_READ_WRITE
    };

    Buffer(StorageBits flags, const void* data, GLuint size) {
        glCreateBuffers(1, &m_gl);
        glNamedBufferStorage(m_gl, size, data, flags);
    }

    Buffer(StorageBits flags, GLuint size) {
        glCreateBuffers(1, &m_gl);
        glNamedBufferStorage(m_gl, size, nullptr, flags);
    }

    ~Buffer() {
        glDeleteBuffers(1, &m_name);
    }

    GLuint gl() const 
        { return m_gl; }

    // return initial storage flags
    StorageBits storageFlags() const {
        GLint flags = 0;
        glGetNamedBufferParameteriv(m_gl, GL_BUFFER_STORAGE_FLAGS, &flags));
        return StorageBits(flags);
    }

    // the buffer size
    GLuint size() const {
        GLint bufferSize = 0;
        glGetNamedBufferParameteriv(m_gl, GL_BUFFER_SIZE, &bufferSize);
        return GLuint(bufferSize);
    }

    // grab pointer to data
    void* map(GLuint offset, GLuint length, MapFlag mapFlags) const {
        // error, buffer is already mapped
        assert(!isMapped());
        // you didn't set the buffer to be mappable on creation!
        assert(storageFlags() & (kMapRead | kMapWrite));
      
        void* ptr = glMapNamedBufferRange(m_gl, 
                        (GLuint)offset, (GLuint)length, mapFlags));
        return ptr;
    }

    bool isMapped() const {
        GLint mapped = 0;
        glGetNamedBufferParameteriv(m_gl, GL_BUFFER_MAPPED, &mapped);
        return mapped != 0;
    }
    
    void flushMappedRange(GLuint offset, GLuint length) const {
        assert(isMapped());
        glFlushMappedNamedBufferRange(m_gl, offset, length);
    }
    
    void unmap() const { 
        assert(isMapped());
        glUnmapNamedBuffer(m_gl);
    }

    void loadSubBuffer(GLuint offset, GLuint numBytes, const void* data) {
        // buffer needs to be dynamic
        assert(storageFlags() & kDynamic);
        glNamedBufferSubData(m_gl, offset, numBytes, data); 
    }

private:
    GLuint m_gl;
};
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I have not heard and fail to find why ```glBindBuffer``` is legacy. Could you provide a source? And what about the other kinds of buffers (different from array buffer), like uniform buffer? Is there a way to use it without binding it? Also, why is using ```glCreateFoo``` and ```glBindFoo``` an error?

Comment: Uniform buffers are the exception, granted. IMO that’s a gaping hole in the spec.

Comment: The problem with the bind methods is that they are modifying global state. The ancient gl spec is clear in how glGen and glBind work, and it isn’t pretty. glGen gives you an unused name. glBind is the point at which that buffer becomes an actual object, so by definition, glBind is a race condition. it should be called glBindAndPossiblyCreateSomething. 

glCreate is atomic. glBind is not. 

If you want to see how it should be done, look at metal or Vulkan. A buffer is a thing with data, and that’s the end of the story. GL isn’t there *yet*

Comment: If uniform buffers are the exception, what about all the others? How do you use for example atomic counter buffer, transform feedback buffer or shader storage buffer without binding them?